# About string to array and array to string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataformat

I use `df.to_csv` function to store the information, and the element's format is `np.float32` in `weight_list`, as shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=weight_list,index=img_names,columns=var_list)
df.to_csv('{}/{}'.format(dirs_path,csv_name))
```

Then, I use `pandas.read_csv` to load the csv file, the value of element surely is string format. How can I convert the string to an `np.float32`?

More information: the type of elements is array in csv file, and arrays have different dimensions as below:
[csv data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1an4X.png)

Comment: A light reminder: please refrain from posting images of code. Copy-paste it into the question and [format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it instead.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about the structure of the data, I would recommend trying `pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv").astype(np.float32)`. `astype` will attempt to cast the data to inside the DataFrame to the specified format.

---

The above should solve your problem, but you may also want to check the version of pandas you are using (and it's documentation for `to_csv` and `read_csv`).

On pandas version `0.23.4` on Python 3.7, I was able to write a dataframe full of float64's to a CSV and successfully read them back with the correct dtypes.

First generate some data, write it, then read it back (assuming your `weight_list` is matrix of floats):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> # Generate dummy dataframe and write it to a CSV
>>> weights=np.random.rand(10,10) # Generate dummy 10x10 matrix of random floats
>>> names=['name{}'.format(i) for i in range(10)] # Generate dummy names and variable names
>>> var_list = ['var{}'.format(i) for i in range(10)]
>>> df0 = pd.DataFrame(data=weights, columns=var_list, index=names)
>>> df0.to_csv("test.csv")
>>> # Load the CSV back into a new dataframe
>>> df1=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
```

Then verify the dtypes are correct (`df0.values` just returns the data inside the DataFrame as a numpy ndarray. You could alternatively check `df0.dtypes`):

```
>>> # Verify the dtypes are float64, as they were originally
>>> df1.values.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> df0.values.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you.Maybe my description is not detailed enough, and I add some details about data structure of my csv file.

Comment: Ah okay, looks like you're trying to store vectors inside the DataFrame cells. You could try serializing to json instead (`df.to_json`, `pd.read_json`). Just a heads up, generally pandas is used for 2D datasets, where each column is a 1D series. You may want to try to restructure your data to make it 2D (maybe expanding each of your columns into 2 1D columns), or maybe explore an option like [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) if you really need N-D dataframes.